# What is Moshi's Equivalent of GSON's gson.fromJson() and gson.toJson()?

Tags: android, json, gson, moshi

I am following this [ROOM tutorial and at some point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mr8YKDh3li4&t=1590s) we need to create Type Converters for ROOM. GSON is being used to parse to and from JSON.

To achieve this we first create this general interface which contains 2 functions to get an object from a JSON String or to parse an object to JSON String. This is so in case you decide to switch to a different library to parse JSON Strings.

```
interface JsonParser {

    //takes the actual JSON String and return an object of our type
    fun <T> fromJson(json: String, type: Type): T?

    //takes our object and return JSON String
    fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Type): String?
}
```

The next step is to create the implementation of the above interface where GSON is used.

```
//JsonParser implementation
class GsonParser (private val gson: Gson):JsonParser {
    override fun <T> fromJson(json: String, type: Type): T? {

        return gson.fromJson(json,type)
    }

    override fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Type): String? {
        return gson.toJson(obj,type)
    }
}
```

For my case I am looking to do the same but with Moshi. Unfortunately Moshi doesn't have `toJson()` or `fromJson()` methods.

[image]

Have tried looking for Moshi methods equivalent GSON's `toJson()` and `fromJson()` but I am not getting anything. How can I go about this?

Comment: `JsonAdapter` has `fromJson()` and `toJson()`. They are shown in [the first examples of the project README](https://github.com/square/moshi#moshi), for both Java and Kotlin. You need to create a `JsonAdapter` for your data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the [Moshi Documentations](https://github.com/square/moshi#moshi) provided by [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) on his above comment"

The solution is to first add dependencies for `Moshi/Retrofit` to your project.

```
// Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'

    //Moshi Library Dependencies - Core Moshi JSON Library and Moshi's Kotlin support and converter factory
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0"
```

Then create a class name `MoshiParser` that implements JsonParser Interface and initialize `Moshi`. For Moshi's annotations to work properly with Kotlin, you just add the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` on Moshi Builder.

The next item is to use Moshi's **JsonAdapter** which takes a generic type of `<T>`. JsonAdpater provides `JsonAdpater.toJson()` and `JsonAdapter.fromJson()`.

```
class MoshiParser() : JsonParser {

    //initialize Moshi
    private val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()


    override fun <T> fromJson(json: String, type: Type): T? {
        
        //use jsonAdapter<T> for generic adapter
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter(type)
        return jsonAdapter.fromJson(json)

    }

    override fun <T> toJson(obj: T, type: Type): String? {

    //use jsonAdapter<T> for generic adapter
        val jsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<T> = moshi.adapter(type)

        return jsonAdapter.toJson(obj)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my extension to handle this with Moshi

```
/*
* [Moshi] extension to transform an object to json
* */
inline fun <reified T> Moshi.objectToJson(data: T): String =
    adapter(T::class.java).toJson(data)

/*
* [Moshi] extension to transform json to an object
* */
inline fun <reified T> Moshi.jsonToObject(json: String): T? =
    adapter(T::class.java).fromJson(json)
```

You'll find more here on gist - [Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/mbobiosio/8eff7b96fe5969c5dd3e1e53a7134fae)